# Initial gnome-terminal tab has the wrong shell

Tags: shell, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, maybe I'm just using the wrong search terms.

I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 20.
My user shell is zsh.

When I open Terminal I get a bash session.  When I click on the new tab button, or new window, new tab menu option, etc. the tab/window opens with a zsh session.

Is there some setting I'm missing?  Is it a bug?  I could work around it by setting a custom command value in the Terminal profile, but I would prefer that it work as intended.

Comment: First make sure your default shell is `zsh` using `echo $SHELL`. You should also check if the button/shortcut/command you are using to open the terminal does not force to run `bash`. Sometimes you find something like `gnome-terminal -e bash`.

Comment: Great suggestion!  Wasn't the issue though, but it really seemed like it.  The only time it launched bash was from the launcher.  Eventually the standard Windows solution fixed it for me... a good reboot.

Comment: Rebooting is the easy solution, but when applying changes to the system just log out of GNOME and log back in for them to take effect (some settings may require a service restart too).